# command to perform arithmetic operation

Tags: awk, sed

I have a set of data on a Linux machine:

```
i_dfi_row_cmd_p1_d[0] ctrl_soft_phy_inst/hbm_ch_tile_4_hbm_tile_inst/o_phy_row_cmd_p1[0] -assign { 0 [ expr 137.88 - 59.248 ]}
```

I want to perform an arithmetic operation for `-assign { 0 [ expr 137.88   59.248 ]}`
like I want to add `X` value to  `59.248`

What I tried to perform this operation is

```
awk '{print $6+3}' filename # its not giving expected answer
```

I tried some changes and commands that I found on Stack Overflow but I haven't achieved what I want. How can I do this?

Comment: What is "X value"? What is "expected answer"?

Comment: What is `$6`? `59.248` is the tenth space-separated field if that is a line from your file. Does `awk '{print $10 + 3}'` give what you expect?

Comment: I suspect that `$6` is not what you want. In the sample line you provided, `$6` is `"["`. What are you expecting `"[" + 3` to be?

Comment: "_I tried some changes and commands that I found on Stack Overflow_" - what did you try? We weren't with you so didn't see what you tried.

Comment: @glennjackman  X is a constant value

Comment: @terdon  $6 is 6th word in the line

Comment: @AndrewRay $6 is 6th word in the line

Comment: Yes, but you want the 10th "word", the 6th word is `[`.

Comment: @terdon okay I consider "-assign { 0 [ expr 137.88   59.248 ]}" as a  whole block,  and this is one line from the and the file consist so many lines.

Comment: The issue is how awk defines words, not you: awk splits on whitespace by default, and this means `-assign { 0 [ expr 137.88 59.248 ]}` is 8 words: `-assign`, `{`, `0`, `[`, `expr`, `137.88`, `59.248` and `]}`.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters have pointed out, you really want to print position 10 (`$10`) of the string. Using that you can easily add your `x` value.

Here is a small example:

`echo "i_dfi_row_cmd_p1_d[0] ctrl_soft_phy_inst/hbm_ch_tile_4_hbm_tile_inst/o_phy_row_cmd_p1[0] -assign { 0 [ expr 137.88 - 59.248 ]}" | awk '{print $10 + 20}'`

This will yield the result `79.248`. As you can see, I simply echoed the line of text provided in your original post printing `$10` and adding the value 20 to it.

Comment: cat all_pin | awk '{$4=""; print $0}' all_pin | awk '{print "eval " $0}' all_pin | sed -f transform.sed all_pin | awk '{print $10+100}' all_pin     
this is my command and i am struck at the last command that you gave me.

Comment: @SanthoshNayakD. please add all this to your question and make sure to include i) a few lines from `all_pin` and ii) the _exact_ output you want from those lines. You don't need `cat file` if you have `awk '{command}' file`. And we have no idea what `transform.sed all_pin` does so we will need to see that too.